# How to properly overwrite clean() method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, clean-urls, django-1.8

I'm trying the Tango With Django Tutorial and the overwrite in the clean() method isn't working to add 'http://' in my urls. What is wrong in this code?

forms.py

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')

        if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
            url += 'http://'
            cleaned_data['url'] = url

        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def add_page(request, category_name_slug):

    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit=False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return category(request, category_name_slug)
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'category': cat, 'form': form}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html', context_dict)
```

add_page.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Add Page{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Add a Page</h1>
    <form id='page_form' method='post' action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Create Page" />
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

The admin is working properly, but the html itself isn't accepting this writing.

Comment: @kaveman> can you insert a breakpoint at the beginning of `clean()` and check the content of `self.cleaned_data` and `self.errors`? I bet the url's not in the former, but the error message already is in the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, since you are cleaning only one field, you should do this in a field-specific method **clean_url**.

```
def clean_url(self):
    url = self.cleaned_data['url']
    # your cleaning here
    return url
```

Comment: Should I still overwrite the clean method? And how do I call it in views.py?

Comment: Just add the outlined clean_url() instead oft your original clean(). As a rule: Cleaning, that only addresses one field should go into a field specific method, cleaning that involves more than one field into clean(). When you call is_valid(), form validation is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

you need this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(PageForm, self).clean() # <-----------
    url = cleaned_data.get('url')
    if url and not url.startswith('http://'):
        url += 'http://'
        cleaned_data['url'] = url
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, when I try adding an URL like 'www.google.com', it still gives me the message 'Please enter a URL'

Comment: @ArrowsX if you are using an url field on model level it will validate and give you the form validation error to add 'http://' to be a valid url. As for overriding the complete clean method just to validate one field is not very django like rather use clean_url(self)

Comment: @doniyor `ModelForm.clean()` just enables uniqueness validation and returns `self.cleaned_data`. Although it is right it ought to be called, it won't fix this issue.