# How to overwrite clean and clean_fieldname for ModelFormMixin

Tags: django, django-forms

I found this
[How to properly overwrite clean() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124329/how-to-properly-overwrite-clean-method)
and this
[Can `clean` and `clean_fieldname` methods be used together in Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878116/can-clean-and-clean-fieldname-methods-be-used-together-in-django-modelform)
but it seems to work differently if one is using the generic class mixins `ModelFormMixin`.
My class is also derived from `ProcessFormView`.
Is `def form_valid(self, form):`  the only point where I can overwrite the form handling process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing *view*s and *form*s. A `CreateView` for example makes use of a `ModelForm` to create an object. But instead of letting the view construct the `ModelForm`, you can specify such form yourself and then pass this as `form_class` to the view.

For example say you have a `Category` model with a `name` field, and you wish to validate that the name of the `Category` is all written in lowercase, you can define a `ModelForm` to do that:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_name(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
        if not data.islower():
            raise ValidationError('The name of the category should be written in lowercase')
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['name']
```

now we can plug in that `ModelForm` as form for our `CategoryCreateView`:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class CategoryCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    form_class = CategoryForm
```

The validation thus should be done in the `ModelForm`, and you can then use that form in your `CreateView`, `UpdateView`, etc.